# Sequentially show multiple dialogs

Tags: android

Depending on different parameters (GPS off, Internet not available, etc.) it's quite possible that my app shows multiple dialogs on application start. This doesn't look nice if multiple dialogs pop up and you can see the dialogs underneath it. That's why I was wondering if it is possible to queue the dialogs (by the system) and they open one after another when the current one has been closed.

I am looking for a solution where I can open the next dialog in the onClickListener is not an option. I would prefer a global solution (not just for app start and a selected amount of dialogs).

Comment: You better use a **cumulative** dialog. Or use **notifications** instead.

Comment: You got to implement your errors handling differently: some do within the view itself, some with dialogs (but then avoid multiple of them), some by notifications etc. It's it to you to implement one of those (just examples)

Comment: @DerGolem Do you have an example for cumulative dialogs? Is this common to show very important information like this in a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might opt for a use a **cumulative** dialog.

It's just a normal dialog in which you put a string like:

```
String info = "GPS: Connected\nWiFi: NOT Connected\n\nBattery: 45%";
```

(just to make an example).

This way you'll concatenate all your messages in a single string, using **\n** (new line) as a connector (make it double, to separate inconsistent info - such as the battery status, in the example).

What you'll get is a **single information panel**.
Like (in the example):

GPS: Connected
WiFi: NOT Connected

Battery: 45%

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! I've also seen an notification example with a hint to turn on wifi in another app I've used. So this is also an option.